# Shopping Cart Estimate Tax Shipping - Issue with shipping totals collect

Tags: php, magento2, cart, shipping-method

I use **WebShopApps_MatrixRates** module on Magento 2 site and module is configured with one delivery method for the region and two other delivery methods for some cities in that region. 

I've setup "Estimate Tax and Shipping" form on Cart Page to display region and city fields. preference for:

```
Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\LayoutProcessor
```

```php
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        $elements = [
            'city' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('City'),
                'options' => $this->bcCitiesOptionsArray,
            ],
            'country_id' => [
                'visible' => false,  //Remove the country
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('Country'),
                'options' => [],
                'value' => null
            ],
            'region_id' => [
                'visible' => true,
                'formElement' => 'select',
                'label' => __('State/Province'),
                'options' => [],
                'value' => null
            ],
            'postcode' => [
                'visible' => false, //Remove Postal Code
                'formElement' => 'input',
                'label' => __('Zip/Postal Code'),
                'value' => null
            ]
        ];

        if (!isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
                'country_id' => $this->countryCollection->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(),
                'region_id' => $this->regionCollection->addAllowedCountriesFilter()->toOptionArray(),
            ];
        }

        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']['children']
            ['address-fieldsets']['children'])
        ) {
            $fieldSetPointer = &$jsLayout['components']['block-summary']['children']['block-shipping']
            ['children']['address-fieldsets']['children'];
            $fieldSetPointer = $this->merger->merge($elements, 'checkoutProvider', 'shippingAddress', $fieldSetPointer);
            $fieldSetPointer['region_id']['config']['skipValidation'] = true;
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
```

and when i select a city with two methods, shipping form with correct methods and prices is loaded.

But after the method is selected, **$addressInformation** parameter is passed to **calculate()** method in class:

```
Magento\Checkout\Model\TotalsInformationManagement
```

```php
public function calculate(
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\TotalsInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->cartRepository->get($cartId);
        $this->validateQuote($quote);

        if ($quote->getIsVirtual()) {
            $quote->setBillingAddress($addressInformation->getAddress());
        } else {
            $quote->setShippingAddress($addressInformation->getAddress());
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)->setShippingMethod(
                $addressInformation->getShippingCarrierCode() . '_' . $addressInformation->getShippingMethodCode()
            );
        }
        $quote->collectTotals();

        return $this->cartTotalRepository->get($cartId);
    }
```

which does not contain information about city.

Because of this, module MatrixRates loads the wrong shipping method from  database and we get two different **$this->getShippingMethod()** and **$rate->getGode()** codes here:

```
Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address
```

```php
    public function requestShippingRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item = null)
    {

        /** @var $request \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest */
        $request = $this->_rateRequestFactory->create();
        $request->setAllItems($item ? [$item] : $this->getAllItems());
        $request->setDestCountryId($this->getCountryId());
        $request->setDestRegionId($this->getRegionId());
        $request->setDestRegionCode($this->getRegionCode());
        $request->setDestStreet($this->getStreetFull());
        $request->setDestCity($this->getCity());
        $request->setDestPostcode($this->getPostcode());
        $request->setPackageValue($item ? $item->getBaseRowTotal() : $this->getBaseSubtotal());
        $packageWithDiscount = $item ? $item->getBaseRowTotal() -
            $item->getBaseDiscountAmount() : $this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount();
        $request->setPackageValueWithDiscount($packageWithDiscount);
        $request->setPackageWeight($item ? $item->getRowWeight() : $this->getWeight());
        $request->setPackageQty($item ? $item->getQty() : $this->getItemQty());

        /**
         * Need for shipping methods that use insurance based on price of physical products
         */
        $packagePhysicalValue = $item ? $item->getBaseRowTotal() : $this->getBaseSubtotal() -
            $this->getBaseVirtualAmount();
        $request->setPackagePhysicalValue($packagePhysicalValue);

        $request->setFreeMethodWeight($item ? 0 : $this->getFreeMethodWeight());

        /**
         * Store and website identifiers specified from StoreManager
         */
        $request->setQuoteStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStoreId());
        $request->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $request->setWebsiteId($this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId());
        $request->setFreeShipping($this->getFreeShipping());
        /**
         * Currencies need to convert in free shipping
         */
        $request->setBaseCurrency($this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency());
        $request->setPackageCurrency($this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency());
        $request->setLimitCarrier($this->getLimitCarrier());
        $baseSubtotalInclTax = $this->getBaseSubtotalTotalInclTax();
        $request->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($baseSubtotalInclTax);

        $result = $this->_rateCollector->create()->collectRates($request)->getResult();

        $found = false;
        if ($result) {
            $shippingRates = $result->getAllRates();

            foreach ($shippingRates as $shippingRate) {
                $rate = $this->_addressRateFactory->create()->importShippingRate($shippingRate);
                if (!$item) {
                    $this->addShippingRate($rate);
                }
                if($this->getShippingMethod() === "_" && $this->getShippingMethod() === null){
                    $this->setShippingMethod($rate->getCode());
                }

                if ($this->getShippingMethod() == $rate->getCode()) {
                    if ($item) {
                        $item->setBaseShippingAmount($rate->getPrice());
                    } else {

                        /** @var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface */
                        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
                        $amountPrice = $store->getBaseCurrency()
                            ->convert($rate->getPrice(), $store->getCurrentCurrencyCode());
                        $this->setBaseShippingAmount($rate->getPrice());
                        $this->setShippingAmount($amountPrice);
                    }

                    $found = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

This condition

```php
 if ($this->getShippingMethod() == $rate->getCode()) {
                    if ($item) {
                        $item->setBaseShippingAmount($rate->getPrice());
                    } else {

                        /** @var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface */
                        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
                        $amountPrice = $store->getBaseCurrency()
                            ->convert($rate->getPrice(), $store->getCurrentCurrencyCode());
                        $this->setBaseShippingAmount($rate->getPrice());
                        $this->setShippingAmount($amountPrice);
                    }

                    $found = true;
                }
```

is not met and function returns **false**

This causes method **collectShippingRates()** in class

```
Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address
```

set shipping method price to 0:

```php
$found = $this->requestShippingRates();
        if (!$found) {
            $this->setShippingAmount(0)->setBaseShippingAmount(0)->setShippingMethod('')->setShippingDescription('');
        }
```

So, how can I add city to **$shippingInformation** variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, and it's very simple! 

The city was not added to the address because of filtering in file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default.js
```

method **loadFromServer()** Line32:

```js
address: _.pick(address, cartCache.requiredFields)
```

So I just override file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/cart/cache.js
```

to my theme and changed **line 78**

from:

```js
        requiredFields: ['countryId', 'region', 'regionId', 'postcode'],
```

to:

```js
        requiredFields: ['countryId', 'region', 'regionId', 'city'],
```

And it solved the problem!